# 0 device supported for my Android App

Tags: android, google-play

Here is my menifest file. I look many other answers on stackoverflow but no one works for me. I also add the screen sized in my menifest file now but not fruitfull. I check all the permission many times and looks fine to me. please help!

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.workplains.androidapp.workmatec"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"

        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"   />

    <compatible-screens>

        <!-- small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <!--Only hdpi and xhdpi for normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

    </compatible-screens>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.workplains.androidapp.workmatec.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".LibraryClasses.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/wmt_logo_transparent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBJYfECN3iNe4Sg6RNx8X_E2rp5VWI-B4g" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".Services.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- for Gingerbread GSF backward compat -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.workplains.androidapp.workmatec" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".Services.GCMIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.IntroductionActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="t4jsample"
                    android:scheme="oauth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.SignupActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_signup" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:logo="@drawable/wmt_logo_transparent" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.NewTaskActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_task" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.ChatActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chat"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.MeetingActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_meeting" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.ReminderActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reminder" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.ToDoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_to_do" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UIElements.FullScreenViewActivity"
            android:label="FullScreen"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeWithActionBar" />

        <provider
            android:name=".FileChooser.LocalStorageProvider"
            android:authorities="com.workplains.androidapp.workmatec.documents"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </provider>

        <service
            android:name=".Services.SocketService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is here:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

You should be targeting the bare minimum that your program will support.  19/22 is pretty high.

Comment: I've changed accordingly but still the same problem exists

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera">
```

To

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

If you don't specify the android:required attribute it defaults to "true". Thus, Google Play Store will assume that the application will not work unless the camera hardware is present.

Once you set android:required to false as given below, Play Store will accept the APK and will show a list of devices available for the application.

You may also look for misspellings on features descriptors. For supported feature descriptors see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference

For more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Comment: I've changed accordingly but still the same problem exists